# Vuejs image loading gives image not found

Tags: image, vue.js, webpack, webpack-encore, webpack-file-loader

I am building a symfony web app and using Webpack Encore to compile VUE components for the frontend.
In the vue component i am trying to load an image which gives me errors whatever i do and its not loading.

1. `:src="require('../../assets/images/logo-white.png').default"`

   I get this error
   **logo-white.fa1b3bfe.png:1 GET http://localhost:8080/try/web/app_dev.php/build/images/logo-white.fa1b3bfe.png 404 (Not Found)**
2. `:src="'../../assets/images/logo-white.png'"`

   I get this error
   **logo-white.png:1 GET http://localhost:8080/try/assets/images/logo-white.png 404 (Not Found)**
3. `src="../../assets/images/logo-white.png"` or `:src="require('../../assets/images/logo-white.png')"`

   I get this error
   **[object%20Module]:1 GET http://localhost:8080/try/web/app_dev.php/[object%20Module] 404 (Not Found)**

I tried many more and i also tried to change webpack configuration setting esModule to false.

This is my project structure:

[image]

So the image is being built successfully.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to .htaccess file

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} app_dev.php/build/*`

`RewriteRule ^app_dev.php/(.*) $1`